# C# wait for timer to end before starting an other timer

Tags: c#, timer

Hi I'm making a UI in Windform and using timers. It's all quite new to me so my understanding of it is kinda of weak. I use timers to make a side menu animation.

The 1st timer is to show the menu. Something like this :

```
private void ShowFullToolsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FonctionsNatives.dessinerOpenGL();
        if (editionToolsMenu.Width >= 200)
            ShowFullTools.Stop();
        else
            editionToolsMenu.Width += 5;                
    }
```

And to hide the side menu I have something similar :

```
private void HideFullMenu_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (editionToolsMenu.Width > 0)
             editionToolsMenu.Width -= 5; 
         else
             HideFullMenu.Stop();
    }
```

The probleme I have is that I want one animation to be COMPLETELY over before starting the other one. I've been using Application.DoEvent(); if the timer.Enable is true, but i'm aware that it's terrible to do that and causes even more bugs. Any solutions?

EDIT1: Sorry for not being precise. Both timer start when a diffrent component is clicked. I also cant write both of the to end, for example: 
    ShowfullMenu.Start():
    HideFullMenu.Start();
Since one does += and the other does -=. They'll be stuck in an infinite loop. Putting the thread to sleep stops the whole UI.

Comment: why can't you simply start the other animation immediately after you stop the first one?

Comment: If i do for example:
    timer1.start
    timer2.start
Since they do += on the side menu and -= on the side menu they'll be stuck in an infinite loop and never get out of it

Comment: I meant what was later suggested in the answer. Your comments are unfortunately unclear and your question, sorry, incomplete. Instead of adding other such comments, edit your question and write a minimum but complete and verifiable example, so that I or other people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the other timer when you are animating one menu and then restart it once you are done animating (and vice-versa). Here is some *non tested* code:

```
private void ShowFullToolsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FonctionsNatives.dessinerOpenGL();
    if (editionToolsMenu.Width >= 200)
    {
        ShowFullTools.Stop();

        // start the other one
        HideFullMenu.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        editionToolsMenu.Width += 5; 
        if (HideFullMenu.Enabled)
        {
            HideFullMenu.Stop();
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. Both timer start when a diffrent component is clicked. I can't really do it that way either because the reste of the code will continue while the timer is enabled. How could I stop and wait for the timer? Putting the thread to sleep stops the whole UI.